# Docker Registry API 2.0 Find Duplicate Tags

Tags: docker, docker-api

I'd like to autonomously query a Docker Registry (API v2) to identify tags that reference the same image. So, for example, if I'm looking at the [Docker Hub golang repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang) and want to find all tags that represent the most recent Alpine image, what's the most efficient way of doing so? For this example the set of tags related to the `:alpine` tag would be `1.12.5-alpine3.9, 1.12-alpine3.9, 1-alpine3.9, alpine3.9, 1.12.5-alpine, 1.12-alpine, 1-alpine, alpine`.

I currently have a functional implementation in python to accomplish this but it's wildly inefficient:

1. Look up all tags, single out the tag I'm interested in (e.g. `:alpine`)
2. For each tag get the manifest, which contains the layers
3. Identify the layers that make up the image for the tag I'm interested in, check all other images for identical layers.

For the `golang` repo there are 980 tags. So while the above solution works it is quite wasteful as it requires nearly 1000 API calls. How is the list within the `Simple Tags` groupings created? Are these generated, or are they built by hand by the maintainers?